# Higher dimensional cross product equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, orthogonality, cross-product

I'm working on a computer vision script for high dimensions that is highly reliant on the cross product in 3D, but as far as I know, it is only formally defined in 3D and 7D. However, experimentally, the property of it I specifically need, the ability to take $n-1$ nD vectors and produce a vector which is orthogonal to all of them, seems to be preserved. I'm unsure if the issues with cross product in higher dimensions are a matter of preserving other properties like anticommutativity, distribution over vector addition, etc., or if a problem eventually arises with orthogonality.

The method I've used so far is as follows:
Form a matrix from the $n-1$ vectors, labeled $v_1,\dots,v_n$, given, then insert and solve for $u$ (I know my annotation is a little bad here):
$$\begin{bmatrix} u_1  & \dots & u_n\\  v_{1_1} & \dots & v_{1_n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ v_{n_1} & \dots & v_{n_n}\end{bmatrix}$$

To solve for $u_i$, we take $(-1)^{i+1}*A_i$, and form a vector of these, where $A_i$ is the minor of the original matrix with respect to row 1, column $i$. This should give us a vector $u$ which is orthogonal to $v_1,\dots,v_n$, and appears to do so experimentally for 4D, but I wouldn't even know where to begin with the general proof, assuming that this is even true for all cases.

Writing out the dot product, I would need something like:
$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}*A_i*v_{j_i}=0$ for all $v_j$.

Does anyone know off the top of their head if this has already been proven somewhere, disproven somewhere, or if there a more feasible way to get an nD vector orthogonal to $n-1$ other vectors?

Comment: Wikipedia mentions [one generalization of the cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product#Generalizations) being a product of $n-1$ vectors in $n$ dimensions. I believe this is what you're looking for. However, it says this is the "Hodge dual of the exterior product," and I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I looked a bit into the sources they cited, and it looks like this may work so long as I can figure out exactly what it's saying to do. I'm somewhat skeptical though because while that paragraph of the wikipedia page puts no restrictions on the input vectors, others say something about needing an orthonormal basis. I'm working in Rn so those exist, but the vectors I'm using aren't going to necessarily be orthonormal already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross product $a \times b$ of two vectors $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is designed to satisfy

$$\langle a\times b, x\rangle = \det(a,b,x),\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^3,$$

where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product. And of course, this relation can be used to prove all the relevant properties of $a \times b$. Likewise, the $n$-dimensional cross product can be defined as a function $\operatorname{Cross}(\cdots)$ of $(n-1)$-vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, given by

$$\langle \operatorname{Cross}(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1}), x \rangle = \det(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1},x),\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

This is almost exactly the same as what you have constructed, possibly except for the sign choice. Indeed, the following observations can be extracted from the properties of determinant.

- $a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}$ are linearly independent if and only if $\operatorname{Cross}(a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}) \neq 0$.
- If $x \in \operatorname{span}(a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1})$, then $\langle \operatorname{Cross}(a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}), x \rangle = 0$. In particular, $a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}$ are orthogonal to $\operatorname{Cross}(a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1})$.
- $\operatorname{Cross}(\cdots)$ is multi-linear, meaning that it is linear in each argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your construction does the job. The fact you need is that any matrix which has a repeated row or column has determinant zero. Your
$\,\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}*A_i*v_{j_i}=0\,$ for all $v_j$ is implied by the fact since when you expand the determinant by minors of a column you get your summation.